# Rearranging equation to solve for $C$ in an integral

Tags: integration

[image]

I tried solving for y, and I get the resulting equation:

[image]

[image]

However, once plugging in $(0, 6)$ you get a power of $e$ that is equal to a negative number. How would you solve this? Is there a different way to find $y$ where $e^c$ does not equate to a negative number?

Comment: Note that there is nothing preventing $c_1$ from being a complex number.

Comment: This can also be interpreted as you mistakenly dropping the absolute value

Comment: You forgot that $\ln(-(y-7))$ is also an antiderivative of $\frac{1}{y-7}$

Comment: The question is build up with copy and paste of pictures. Please investigate more effort and time to ask questions and use mathjax/latex for math content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $$\ln|y-7| = \frac{x^2}{2} - 8x +C$$which implies $$|y-7| = e^{\frac{x^2}{2} - 8x +C} \implies y = e^{\frac{x^2}{2} - 8x +C} + 7 \ \  \text{or} \ \ y = -e^{\frac{x^2}{2} - 8x +C}+7$$If you want the real solution and $y(0) = 6$ then $$6 = -e^{C} + 7 \implies e^C = 1 \implies C = 0$$

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! I didn't realize dropping the absolute value should give me two equations.

Comment: @Shurim I'm glad it was helpful. You can accept it as answer if you would like.